# sed: what does "/ " mean?

Tags: sed

```
x=`src/lstat64 $TEST_DIR/$tmp.1 | sed -n -e '/ Links: /s/.*Links: *//p'`
```

In this script. I understand this part `"/s/.*Links: *//p'"`
the only thing I don't understand is `'/ Links: '`  what does `"/ "` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/ Links: /` is an address filter. It means: *"Apply the following operation only to those lines which match the filter."* In this case the filter is a regex; it could also be a line number, a line area, a start regex and stop regex combination and even a *"every n-th line"* condition with some `sed` implementations.

Answer (score 3):

You have a misunderstand. your command can be interpreted as:

```
sed - n -e '/pattern/ s/pattern/replace pattern/p'
```

So the first two `/` is belong to `/pattern/`, which meaning match a regex:

```
/regexp/
          Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.
```

Answer (score 2):

> the only thing I don't understand is '/ Links: '

Your `sed` expressions *filters* lines matching the pattern `Links:` (with a leading and trailing space) and performs the substitution

```
s/.*Links: *//
```

Moreover, using `-n` suppresses automatic printing of pattern space and `p` prints the current pattern space.

To summarize, the `sed` pipeline would print only the lines matching `Links:` in the input *after* performing the substitution `s/.*Links: *//`.

Quoting from `man sed`:

```
   -n, --quiet, --silent

          suppress automatic printing of pattern space


   p      Print the current pattern space.

   /regexp/
          Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.


   s/regexp/replacement/
          Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If
          successful, replace that portion matched with replacement. The
          replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that
          portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special
          escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding matching
          sub-expressions in the regexp.
```